# Chaining promises with $q in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to chain promises so that doQuery(0) executes then doQuery(1), etc... sequentially until doQuery(9).

My problem is that i is always equals to 10 in the callback function.

doQuery(0) executes then doQuery(10).

How do I pass each value of i in the callback function?

```
var promise = doQuery(0);
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        doQuery(i);
    });
};
```

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using Angular.js, you should use it's [bind function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bind) here:

```
var promise = doQuery(0);
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(angular.bind(null, doQuery, i));
}
```

Without relying on Angular.js, you could use a closure to make a copy of `i` for each callback function (rather than having them all share the single copy of `i` in the outer scope):

```
var promise = doQuery(0);
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(function(i){
        return function(){
            doQuery(i);
        };
    }(i));
}
```

In modern Javascript engines you can also use the native [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var promise = doQuery(0);
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(doQuery.bind(null, i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return each to-be-chained promise from the `then` callback, otherwise it will likely fail. To pass the right `i` value to each callback, see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

```
var promise = doQuery(0);
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) (function(ii) {
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        return doQuery(ii);
    });
})(i);
```